# My friend accidentally drank camphor water and also swallowed a piece of camphor

Tags: first-aid, poison

> A friend of mine drank camphor water today he also swallowed a small
>   piece of camphor.

I searched for the [side effects](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-709-camphor.aspx?activeingredientid=709&activeingredientname=camphor#vit_sideeffects) in google it is said that after taking directly by mouth in 5 to 90 minutes vomiting will be occurred and also in some case it will also include to death.

> I'm happy to say that my friend didn't get any vomiting but he is saying that his stomach is having some burning sensation to some extent,that means is he safe now or any medical
>   advice needed??

[image]

[image]

Comment: "in some case it will also include to death", I would suggest that i immediately seek medical advice to avoid any serious complications.

Comment: @Khan But any of the mentioned is not being visible in him its been 5 hrs still he is doing good .

Comment: Maybe it may take time for camphor to effect his body or maybe he is doing fine or not effected by it..just that with statutory warning stating that it may lead to death is something u shouldn't ignore..just consult a doctor..better safe than sorry..

Comment: dh47, as stated in other comments, this is something that your friend needs to seek personal medical advice for immediately. It is just not safe to rely on folks on the internet to provide care in this circumstance. If, after helping your friend obtain appropriate care, you would like to come back and re-phrase this to be a more general question about camphor, you can [edit] it and we can se about re-opening. Thanks.

Comment: I love to listen from downvoter's what's wrong did they find in this question??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the emergency services or the anti-poisoning centre **right away**. Don't waste your time looking for effects on the internet.

Keep calm, and:

- Tell your name, phone number, location,
- Tell this is for a poisoning, and tell the victim's gender and age
- Tell what was swallowed, how, how much and how long ago
- Don't hang up the phone before instructed to do so

They will guide you and tell you what to do, should something needs to be done.

**Don't take any initiative outside the instructions you will receive**. 
Don't give water, don't give milk, don't to try to make the person to vomit, don't give any medication, and ask the person not to move.

I'll elaborate (and reference) this answer further later should the question be reopen once made more general, but **in the interest of the victim do this right now, even if he/she seems to feel good.**